# Juntar dos consultas una al lado de la otra

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo  dos consultas iguales pero cada consulta esta en diferente base de datos

```
SELECT T0.codlote AS Lote1,sum(T0.peso) AS peso1,T1.fecha AS Fecha1
FROM [1_Datos].dbo.tblmvto_lotes T0
INNER JOIN tbllotes T1 ON T1.codlote = T0.codlote
GROUP BY T0.codlote, T1.fecha
ORDER BY T0.codlote
---
SELECT R0.codlote AS Lote2,sum(R0.peso) AS peso2,R1.fecha AS Fecha2
FROM [2_Datos].dbo.tblmvto_lotes R0
INNER JOIN tbllotes R1 ON R1.codlote = R0.codlote
GROUP BY R0.codlote,R1.fecha
ORDER BY R0.codlote
```

me muestra lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las junte con el union luego hice una subconsulta, pero no obtengo el resultado.

```
SELECT V1.Lote1, V1.peso1,Fecha1 FROM(
SELECT T0.codlote AS Lote1,sum(T0.peso) AS peso1,T1.fecha AS Fecha1
FROM [1_Datos].dbo.tblmvto_lotes T0
INNER JOIN tbllotes T1 ON T1.codlote = T0.codlote
GROUP BY T0.codlote, T1.fecha
UNION ALL
SELECT R0.codlote AS Lote2,sum(R0.peso) AS peso2,R1.fecha AS Fecha2
FROM [2_Datos].dbo.tblmvto_lotes R0
INNER JOIN tbllotes R1 ON R1.codlote = R0.codlote
GROUP BY R0.codlote,R1.fecha) V1
```

El resultado que espero es que la segunda consulta me quede al lado derecho de la primera, de la siguiente forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no logro hacer esta consulta, ¿Si es con la subconsulta  o como se debería hacer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para esto no debes usar un `UNION`, sino algún `JOIN` (sin saber cuál set de datos tiene más fechas o lotes, te recomendaría inicialmente usar un `FULL JOIN`).

```
SELECT *
FROM (
       SELECT T0.codlote AS Lote1,sum(T0.peso) AS peso1,T1.fecha AS Fecha1
       FROM [1_Datos].dbo.tblmvto_lotes T0
       INNER JOIN tbllotes T1 ON T1.codlote = T0.codlote
       GROUP BY T0.codlote, T1.fecha) x
FULL JOIN (    
           SELECT R0.codlote AS Lote2,sum(R0.peso) AS peso2,R1.fecha AS Fecha2
           FROM [2_Datos].dbo.tblmvto_lotes R0
           INNER JOIN tbllotes R1 ON R1.codlote = R0.codlote
           GROUP BY R0.codlote,R1.fecha) y
     ON x.Lote1 = y.Lote1
     AND x.Fecha = y.Fecha
ORDER BY x.Lote1, y.Lote1;
```

Ojo que en tus consultas iniciales no hace mucho sentido agrupar por Fecha, porque es un punto demasiado pequeño al incluir la hora. Quizás deberías convertirlo solo a fecha (para que llegue hasta nivel día) y de esa forma hacer el `JOIN` (como está ahora lo más probable es que el join no haga match en ninguna fila por esta fecha). Quedaría de esta forma:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
       SELECT T0.codlote AS Lote1,sum(T0.peso) AS peso1,CONVERT(date,T1.fecha) AS Fecha1
       FROM [1_Datos].dbo.tblmvto_lotes T0
       INNER JOIN tbllotes T1 ON T1.codlote = T0.codlote
       GROUP BY T0.codlote, CONVERT(date,T1.fecha)) x
FULL JOIN (    
           SELECT R0.codlote AS Lote2,sum(R0.peso) AS peso2,CONVERT(date,R1.fecha) AS Fecha2
           FROM [2_Datos].dbo.tblmvto_lotes R0
           INNER JOIN tbllotes R1 ON R1.codlote = R0.codlote
           GROUP BY R0.codlote,CONVERT(date,R1.fecha)) y
     ON x.Lote1 = y.Lote1
     AND x.Fecha = y.Fecha
ORDER BY x.Lote1, y.Lote1;
```

Comment: Gracias, era lo que esperaba.